# Standard Deviation calculation not working in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, variance, exponent

So I was using this method that calculates the standard deviation of my array but it doesn't seem to give me the right value.

```
double numbers[] = new double[10];
double sumOfAllItems = 0;

private double total()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        sumOfAllItems += numbers[i];
    }

    return sumOfAllItems;
}

public double mean()
{
    // working
    **sumOfAllItems = 0;**
    return total() / numbers.Length;
}

// numbers are from (1-10) (too lazy to type up all of them.

public double variance()
{
    // each (value - mean) squared
    double summationsTotal = 0; // (numbers[i] - mean() squared

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        summationsTotal += Math.Pow(numbers[i] - mean(), 2);
    }

    return summationsTotal / (numbers.Length - 1);
}
```

I manually calculated the Variance and it gave me an answer of a 9.166666. This is for sample formula.

However, when I calculated it on my GUI, it gave me 866.25 instead. Is there anything wrong with this code?

Comment: Can you post the code for `mean()`?

Comment: Possibly because of BODMAS? Have you tried subtracting the `mean` from the `numbers[i]` first, and then squaring it?

Comment: The problem is in `total()` it doesn't initialise to zero and it gets called more than once

Comment: Initialize `sumofAllItems` in `total()`, or make better, make it local.

Comment: Isn't Math.pow supposed to do that? Like subtract what's inside the parameter before it squares? @user959631

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok you have got your answer. I would suggest an alternate approach with Linq goodies and extension methods.

```
public static double StandardDeviation(this ICollection<double> values)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(values.Variance());
}

public static double Variance(this ICollection<double> values)
{
    if (values.Count == 0)
        return 0;

    var avg = values.Average();
    return values.Select(x => Math.Pow(x - avg, 2)).Sum() / values.Count;
}
```

Call it like:

```
var variance = numbers.Variance(); //or so
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

```
double sumOfAllItems = 0;

private double total()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        sumOfAllItems += numbers[i];
    }

    return sumOfAllItems;
}
```

It should be:

```
double sumOfAllItems = 0;

private double total()
{
   sumOfAllItems = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        sumOfAllItems += numbers[i];
    }

    return sumOfAllItems;
}
```

It would be more efficient too to cache the mean rather than recalculating it inside the variance function - it's not going to change. Something like:

```
public double variance()
{
    // each (value - mean) squared
    double dMean - mean();
    double summationsTotal = 0; // (numbers[i] - mean() squared

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        summationsTotal += Math.Pow(numbers[i] - dMmean, 2);
    }

    return summationsTotal / (numbers.Length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the square root of the square of differences and then average them. So add a square root in there.  And when you do the division don't use -1 as you are not dealing with indexing but the actual count of the items.

Answer (score 0):

You are recalculating total() many times without zeroing it first. So your total gets large wrong value. For quick fix you should zero the `sumOfAllItems` variable in your `total()` method. But you would do better if you too calculated the `mean()` just for one time in `variance()` before entering the for loop. Your code will get faster.

Comment: So I guess for my mean method I have to do this? sumOfAllIems = 0 after I return?

Comment: put it at the beginning like in Roger Rowlands answer

Comment: I tried this and it worked. I reset sumOfAllItems = 0 before I returned.